# xcolor changes size of numbers of the siunitx package

Tags: color, koma-script, siunitx

When using `siunitx` in combination with `xcolor` the size of the numbers defined by `\num` changes for some instances. See following MWE. The second 1 in the denominator gets smaller if `xcolor` is used. This only happens with KOMA-Script document classes, not with the standard document classes. The order of loading the packages makes no difference. Has someone an idea how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    $ 10^{\frac{1}{1 - \num{1}}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't really explain why this happens but it would be anyways good practice to do either all numbers inside a `siunitx` command or none.

Comment: It happens with other classes too, if you use e.g. 12pt fontsize. With color there is an additional group.

Comment: I notice no difference as of September 2023

Comment: @mbert Indeed, the problem only occurs with old versions (e.g. of TeX Live 2020). So update fixes the problem and therefore the question should be closed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by an update, hence a comment recommended a close.